# Is there a library that helps storing hibernate data into AWS S3 instead of in the database?

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a library that helps storing hibernate data into AWS S3 instead of in the database?

I’m looking for something easy to use.

Comment: Hibernate is an object-relational mapper, designed to manage a program's interaction with a relational database. S3 isn't a relational database. If you want a good answer you'll need to describe what you're trying to do, not what technologies you want to use to do it.

Comment: I have an image entity and want to save the metadata in the database but not the file.

Comment: Can't you simply save the image to S3, and the metadata in a database? What specific issue are you facing?